# ISO 8601 Field to Python DateTime Field

Tags: python, django, api, datetime

I am taking in a DateTimeField from an API with the format of "2016-08-09T02:16:15Z". I am using the code below to parse it and turn it to what I thought was a date time field, but am getting an error from one of my class methods to compare the time. Please see the parsing code below:

```
time= dateutil.parser.parse(x['MatchTime']) #MatchTime is the ISO 8601 field
```

The time seems to be pulling correctly, but when I add it to my Game model, pasted below, **my is_live** method is giving me an error

Game model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    livePick = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def is_live(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        now.astimezone(timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)
        if now < self.time:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This is the error I am getting when I run the script to add in the Game with the time

```
line 34, in is_live
if now < self.time:
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.datetime() < NoneType()
```

Update:
Time is added to the Game model with the following

```
g = Game.objects.create(team1=team1, team2=team2)
g.time = time 
g.save()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `time` in your model is nullable, and is empty (`None`) for the model instance for which the comparison fails. This raises an exception when you try to compare it with a `datetime` object.

You need to account for the null possibility in your logic, e.g.,:

```
if self.time is not None and now < self.time:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: I am trying to make sure the field is not empty with this API call: time= dateutil.parser.parse(x['MatchTime']) -- MatchTime is a field from the API with ISO 8601 date data. I know that the call is converting the ISO 8601 date to a formatted date, but the python is not reading it as a dateTime field clearly

Comment: How is the result of that function being written to the model instance variable? is `time` definitely being saved to `self.time`?

Comment: Added the code above to show how the API pull is being saved to my Game model. Please let me know if you'd like to see anything else